# Is there anything wrong with passing a useRef to a child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-forwardref

```
const ParentComp = ({}) {
  const p_ref = useRef();
  return <ChildComp p_ref={p_ref}/>
}

const ChildComp = ({p_ref}) {
  return <div ref={p_ref} />
}
```

I have read somewhere of the `forwardRef` of react. Do I need a `forwardRef` to do what I am attempting to do, or is it find?

I have tested my code as is, and everything works as expected.

Comment: useRef is primarily used to access and manipulate the DOM or store mutable values without triggering re-renders. It provides a mutable reference that persists across component renders. On the other hand, useState is used for managing component state, triggering re-renders when the state updates.

Comment: Yes, you can pass a ref to a child component, but in this case you should be using `forwardRef` see: [Exposing a DOM node to the parent component](https://react.dev/reference/react/forwardRef#usage) in the docs